# NVIDIA control panel has stopped working in windows 10 technical preview.Any fix?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, windows-10-preview

I downloaded the Windows 10 technical preview.And when i tried to run assassin's creed with the GPU High-performance NVIDIA processor the game has stopped running, then when i open NVIDIA control panel i had a message which said "NVIDIA Control Panel Application , 8.1.760.0 has stopped working".I uninstall this gpu and restarted my laptop then i check for updates and i installed the device but in vain i still have    the same problem

Comment: Take a look: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/805455/geforce-drivers/windows-10-technical-preview-2-display-driver-feedback-thread-1-23-15-/6/

Comment: The simplest solution.  Only install the drivers the control panel isn't required to function and likely is NOT supported on Windows 10 at this time.

Comment: What Nvidia card is installed and which driver are you using? Also which Preview build number? If you're running into the problem I had that matters and I can answer your question.